# Why doesn't the getrawtransaction command with the verbose flag include the confirmations field?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, getrawtransaction

According to the official Bitcoin documentation, getrawtransaction should return a confirmations field, but I don't see that field in the response.

https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getrawtransaction.html

My response is:

```
{
'txid': 'dcee66416a499013e1898dbb9eeb297af0ea721990dfd114471c810b24d9c914',
'hash': '6aee71cbbe9a9573fea25dbc6765b619d2c568e434fb642ceee4864ad527282d',
'version': 1,
'size': 770,
'vsize': 688,
'weight': 2750,
'locktime': 0,
'vin': [{
    'txid': '4ab11d2c30cb7d60d335914026ca8a7b11f9b90c5ea403b14ef5bdf33707eef2',
    'vout': 0,
    'scriptSig': {'asm': '', 'hex': ''},
    'txinwitness': [
        '3045022100be6e832262d847871d5ca58790fd6731a148bf8282ae71b39cdfe6befd859f4102201c0f8ccb451bdb8c0e2f7cc02d7a7018882e478aa23aed15f2ccce75ad88e50a01',
        '02174ee672429ff94304321cdae1fc1e487edf658b34bd1d36da03761658a2bb09'],
    'sequence': 4294967295}],
'vout': [{
    'value': 0.0022,
    'n': 0,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': '0 34cc50701f55633fa883d5e763d7ef699a9e2bff',
        'desc': 'addr(bc1qxnx9quql243nl2yr6hnk84l0dxdfu2llmqydxh)#0j0l9gs3',
        'hex': '001434cc50701f55633fa883d5e763d7ef699a9e2bff',
        'address': 'bc1qxnx9quql243nl2yr6hnk84l0dxdfu2llmqydxh',
        'type': 'witness_v0_keyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.09642829,
    'n': 1,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': '0 dc6bf86354105de2fcd9868a2b0376d6731cb92f',
        'desc': 'addr(bc1qm34lsc65zpw79lxes69zkqmk6ee3ewf0j77s3h)#t4dkz7rz',
        'hex': '0014dc6bf86354105de2fcd9868a2b0376d6731cb92f',
        'address': 'bc1qm34lsc65zpw79lxes69zkqmk6ee3ewf0j77s3h',
        'type': 'witness_v0_keyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.00656953,
    'n': 2,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': '0 97db6940960345d01bcd9829c890e63cb591d906',
        'desc': 'addr(bc1qjldkjsykqdzaqx7dnq5u3y8x8j6erkgxq4rk3s)#da7p060e',
        'hex': '001497db6940960345d01bcd9829c890e63cb591d906',
        'address': 'bc1qjldkjsykqdzaqx7dnq5u3y8x8j6erkgxq4rk3s',
        'type': 'witness_v0_keyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.01133746,
    'n': 3,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 bce27a3df6ed27a9e1829ba637fbbb2ba58b2119 OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(3JukGYLAunYfGsWBgCXrLY2QZMDqyBCX4m)#lc27xek3',
        'hex': 'a914bce27a3df6ed27a9e1829ba637fbbb2ba58b211987',
        'address': '3JukGYLAunYfGsWBgCXrLY2QZMDqyBCX4m',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.00358816,
    'n': 4,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 688ac3f6acb233537fd02225ac830eed3a1e0015 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG',
        'desc': 'addr(1AXmWYcpWYrFZvCMcFJXYFqBaM83msjzLZ)#qfc9tky9',
        'hex': '76a914688ac3f6acb233537fd02225ac830eed3a1e001588ac',
        'address': '1AXmWYcpWYrFZvCMcFJXYFqBaM83msjzLZ',
        'type': 'pubkeyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.0036425,
    'n': 5,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 4c32aa1bf49890401602eafb4f21d543e7861997 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG',
        'desc': 'addr(17wu3oxFEq1pdQSA8Ym17ExHEr2h7CCH9r)#v45ww8xp',
        'hex': '76a9144c32aa1bf49890401602eafb4f21d543e786199788ac',
        'address': '17wu3oxFEq1pdQSA8Ym17ExHEr2h7CCH9r',
        'type': 'pubkeyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.01822233,
    'n': 6,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 595e840a8971c756a7048b58546c5d682ab8fd4f OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG',
        'desc': 'addr(199YN9QDSBaeAEnzs4vXGNnrhp7GujcpTv)#ccy6x25y',
        'hex': '76a914595e840a8971c756a7048b58546c5d682ab8fd4f88ac',
        'address': '199YN9QDSBaeAEnzs4vXGNnrhp7GujcpTv',
        'type': 'pubkeyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.01246382,
    'n': 7,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': '0 c67052c931f4fe27d8ad41f5530748e906119f70',
        'desc': 'addr(bc1qcec99jf37nlz0k9dg864xp6gayrpr8msq7uf8v)#fcxddsjw',
        'hex': '0014c67052c931f4fe27d8ad41f5530748e906119f70',
        'address': 'bc1qcec99jf37nlz0k9dg864xp6gayrpr8msq7uf8v',
        'type': 'witness_v0_keyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.00115586,
    'n': 8,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 15ca0ae6571f7409828c1a632a12337023522e2e OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(33gE9jg3whjTgx34X5CtDMzHhceAnTDedY)#te8pfcrg',
        'hex': 'a91415ca0ae6571f7409828c1a632a12337023522e2e87',
        'address': '33gE9jg3whjTgx34X5CtDMzHhceAnTDedY',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.00016101,
    'n': 9,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 f4f34136a58f50e5ef91cbf0b974d94526f967fb OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(3Q2CCz9EfCLmGL8fPyYkx331ShyWiVBe5F)#jvya2pyl',
        'hex': 'a914f4f34136a58f50e5ef91cbf0b974d94526f967fb87',
        'address': '3Q2CCz9EfCLmGL8fPyYkx331ShyWiVBe5F',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.1998,
    'n': 10,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 5d75cb96d82cb1b30ebe30b0da798ef432860e1c OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(3ADBswe2jxr9XaLJq491BdDiQXDMinBjZB)#2e484r49',
        'hex': 'a9145d75cb96d82cb1b30ebe30b0da798ef432860e1c87',
        'address': '3ADBswe2jxr9XaLJq491BdDiQXDMinBjZB',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.36000101,
    'n': 11,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_DUP OP_HASH160 9e04a763f86d7c775080c82cb868744df17ffd69 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG',
        'desc': 'addr(1FQXLfcS9XfbE4ocYZDFPJUHS8VPb1Twot)#jwtnh5zs',
        'hex': '76a9149e04a763f86d7c775080c82cb868744df17ffd6988ac',
        'address': '1FQXLfcS9XfbE4ocYZDFPJUHS8VPb1Twot',
        'type': 'pubkeyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.0079,
    'n': 12,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 9153604006c8e7766077e63b382b938e946f1f21 OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(3EwRnRXFo5BsHGtxG2vyZaSfdpyMkTL1ni)#f4kmy4h0',
        'hex': 'a9149153604006c8e7766077e63b382b938e946f1f2187',
        'address': '3EwRnRXFo5BsHGtxG2vyZaSfdpyMkTL1ni',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.0023,
    'n': 13,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 72b9cd3b44ac06af4b634d8946b8050287face0d OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(3C9dY94k9sGG3umKvmuXfsPvXhbygqiZP5)#ryq7mrt7',
        'hex': 'a91472b9cd3b44ac06af4b634d8946b8050287face0d87',
        'address': '3C9dY94k9sGG3umKvmuXfsPvXhbygqiZP5',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.0113,
    'n': 14,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 2707f01590dfbf62c09f7b4d20066ec476d3e305 OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(35FPnZ9rZ89U3ERsJEcL6qLRcFqR7BnBNE)#v3uvz2g8',
        'hex': 'a9142707f01590dfbf62c09f7b4d20066ec476d3e30587',
        'address': '35FPnZ9rZ89U3ERsJEcL6qLRcFqR7BnBNE',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.03622237,
    'n': 15,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': '0 8052c878f073cec9a99dbe8f43dcacbbbe7f3745',
        'desc': 'addr(bc1qspfvs78sw08vn2vah6858h9vhwl87d69w3wt8w)#0culwng7',
        'hex': '00148052c878f073cec9a99dbe8f43dcacbbbe7f3745',
        'address': 'bc1qspfvs78sw08vn2vah6858h9vhwl87d69w3wt8w',
        'type': 'witness_v0_keyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.01776,
    'n': 16,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': '0 2326e0fbefaf598fa6cd25e9df54939a6864edcf',
        'desc': 'addr(bc1qyvnwp7l04avclfkdyh5a74ynnf5xfmw098ue4j)#lgk3vvks',
        'hex': '00142326e0fbefaf598fa6cd25e9df54939a6864edcf',
        'address': 'bc1qyvnwp7l04avclfkdyh5a74ynnf5xfmw098ue4j',
        'type': 'witness_v0_keyhash'}}, {
    'value': 0.00269325,
    'n': 17,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': 'OP_HASH160 0a158c71f81a11f28e9d0f779e0ab9e850b17316 OP_EQUAL',
        'desc': 'addr(32cLVgjzF6wK2M9WqCjpEBF27rZRt1fp2a)#ad7mark9',
        'hex': 'a9140a158c71f81a11f28e9d0f779e0ab9e850b1731687',
        'address': '32cLVgjzF6wK2M9WqCjpEBF27rZRt1fp2a',
        'type': 'scripthash'}}, {
    'value': 0.00364159,
    'n': 18,
    'scriptPubKey': {
        'asm': '0 ef8169ec58bfb23773e6c280a23923b332773887',
        'desc': 'addr(bc1qa7qknmzch7erwulxc2q2ywfrkve8wwy8z6mtsk)#n0rm7tvu',
        'hex': '0014ef8169ec58bfb23773e6c280a23923b332773887',
        'address': 'bc1qa7qknmzch7erwulxc2q2ywfrkve8wwy8z6mtsk',
        'type': 'witness_v0_keyhash'}}],
'hex': '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'
```

}

Comment: Are you running Bitcoin Core? If so, what version of Bitcoin Core are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Was the tx confirmed when you ran this? My node returns this, as expected:

```
  "blockhash": "000000000000000000033fa977be990449444794ecd5bb09826c9b5e8fcd8e4c",
  "confirmations": 146,
  "time": 1682292871,
  "blocktime": 1682292871
```

If the block isn't confirmed, those fields are omitted.

Comment: If the response does not include a `confirmations` field, you can assume that the transaction is still in the mempool, right?

Comment: @Andrei Mukhametvaleev, Yes